# How to calculate relative rotation and position of a point to another point without using parent-child hiearchy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, parent-child, point-clouds

I have an incoming real time point cloud (approximately 300K points) from a depth camera. I've managed to visualize the data using GPU instancing and a compute shader on 60+ FPS. My only issue is that the point cloud is incoming in world coordinates. I would like to position and rotate the point cloud relative to another GameObject. Basically if I rotate the "parent" object, the point cloud acts like its child.

How could I calculate the position of the points relative to another GameObject's position and rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Using `transform.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint` was the answer.

Here is the line of code in context:

```
PointCloud[i].position = Pivot.localToWorldMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(incomingDataPositions[i]);
```